# How to change the text color of items in MaterialAlertDialog?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

I am trying to change the text color of the items in a single choice MaterialViewAlertDialog. I achieved to change the "RadioButton" color and the title color but I can't change the text color of the items. For now I am using the following style:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorText</item>
</style>
```

I also tried to cahnge the text color of the items with textAppearanceListItem but it didn't work.

Comment: do you set the theme in java?

Comment: Yes I set the theme and for instance <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorText</item> is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the color of the text in the items you can use something like:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle" ns2:ignore="NewApi">@style/myCheckedTextView</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
  <style name="myCheckedTextView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CheckedTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

Otherwise you can also use:

```
<style name="AlertDialog"  
   parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
     <item name="colorSecondary">@color/selected</item> <!-- selected -->
 </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working great. But ns2:ignore="NewApi" seems unnecessary to me (I don't have a warning on Android Studio without it). Is there a specific reason for adding ns2:ignore="NewApi" ?

Comment: It is the same of @SuppressLint("NewApi")